# Does MIP* = RE algebrize?

Tags: quantum-computing, interactive-proofs

Does the [MIP* = RE](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.04383) result [algebrize](https://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/alg.pdf)?  (It doesn’t relativize, as noted [here](https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=4512#comment-1828321).)

If it doesn’t algebrize, is there a more complicated similar notion that it does satisfy?

Comment: Algebraization is about complexity while re is about computability.

Comment: I would it is no.

Comment: @VS. this comment would also have applied to relativization, wouldn't it? *(sorry, updated my comment while you were answering, now the order is messed up)*

Comment: @VS. Please feel free to write up an answer if your intuition can be expanded into a proof or argument.  As it is I'm not sure how to interpret "complexity" vs. "computability" formally: both notions are about sets of languages, and the question is already a well-defined question about sets of languages.